Conditional expectation of the second occurrence of an $n$-digit pattern knowing that it occurred in the beginning of the string $p$
I was confronted with the problem of proving the following lemma :
Consider the semi-infinite sequence of digits $d_i$.\begin{align} d = [d_0,d_1,d_2,...  \end{align}
We have $L \geq 2$ possible digits, and each digit $d_i$ is selected independently and has a probability of $L^{-1}$ of being any of the $L$ possible digits.
We have $p$ which is an n-digit pattern that we're looking. ($p = [p_1,p_2,...,p_n]$) and we have the following notation :
\begin{align} d[i,j) = [d_i, ..., d_{j-1}] \end{align}
We define the random variable $x$ such that $x = i$ if and only if
\begin{align} d[i,i+n) = p \end{align}
\begin{align} d[j,j+n) \neq p,   1\leq j < i \end{align}
How can we prove that for any n-digit pattern $p$ , n $\geq$ 1:
\begin{align}  E(x | d[0,n)=p)= L^{n} \end{align}
(Notice that $x$ takes values starting from 1 not 0)
For instance : if $L=2$ and that the desired sequence is 00 (i.e, $n=2$ then we want to prove that: $E\{x|d[0,2)=00\} =2^{2}$
(NOTE :  The problem from the paper On the Expected Duration of a Search for a Fixed Pattern
in Random Data by P. TOLSTRUP NIELSEN published in IEEE transactions on information theory of 1973.)

This is hard to follow.  Your sequence begins with $d_1$ according to the definition so what does $d[0,n)$ mean?   But let's say you meant your sequence to start with $d_0$...then, given that the initial string happens to be the desired string, we would know for certain that $x=0$, right?

I suggest:  edit your post, first to clean up the notation and then, more importantly, to include an explicit example. Say $L=2$ and that the desired sequence is $00$.  Then, in  that case, what is it you are trying to prove?

@lulu I think you're right, I made the mistake of adhering to the notation of the source (which is the paper that I included below) without fully explaining the notation. In the paper, the author called d a random data stream, and then he said that we "shall assume for convenience" that d is preceded by an initial digit $d_0$ so that the notation $d[i,j)=[d_i, ..,d_j)$ for $i \geq 0$ is justifiable.

@lulu "given that the initial string happens to be the desired string, we would know for certain that $x=0$" >> That is exactly what I thought, but the proof of the author seems to ignore any discussion of this point.And this caused me confusion.

Well, as it stands I don't think the question makes any sense.  If you know that the infinite string starts with the desired finite string, then the random variable $x$ is fully determined, and it is just the starting index (be that $0$ or $1$).

@lulu I guess I figured what the problem states. the random variable $x$ takes values starting from 1, i.e, we're looking for the next occurance of the pattern $p$ knowing that it is the starting pattern of the data stream $d$. (I invite you to look at the original paper: "10.1109/tit.1973.1055064")

My only guess:  the "first occurrence"  of the desired string $p$ doesn't count the occurrence which starts at $d_0$.  So you are then looking for what I'd have called the "second" occurrence.  But then, of course, it should probable be $L^n$, not $L^{-n}$ and I would worry about cases in which the sequence can "restart" from the middle.  That is to say, if you desired sequence is $00$, then you have two occurrences of it in $000$ whereas this is not possible if the desired sequence was $01$.  But, these are a lot of guesses and I may be far off the intended mark.

@lulu yes you are completly right, the expected value that we want to prove is $L^{n}$

@lulu I've just adjusted the post. Do you think it's clear right now ?

The  paper cited in the question has a proof.

@Fnacool I didn't understand the solution. The relationship between $E(x|d[0,n)=p)$ and expected value of the indicator random is not clear to me. Can you clarify it ?

Sketch, By LLN (for IID sequences, that's why we start from the pattern)  the time of the $m$-recurrence is asymptotically equivalent to $E[T] m$. On the other hand, by the LLN for weakly dependent sequences (proved in paper), the number of  appearances by time $t$ is asymptotically equivalent to $L^{-n} t$. Combine. By the first, the sequence of times    $m E[T]$ is asymptotically equivalent to the time of the $m$-th appearance. By the second, at  these times we have $  L^{-n} E[T] m $ appearances, so $m$ and $L^{-n} E[T] m$ are asymptotically equivalent, hence $E[T] = L^n$.

Consider the following Markov chain. There are $L^n$ possible states, one for each sequence of $n$ digits. The initial state is $p$. Then, for each $k\ge 1$, the $k^{\text{th}}$ state is the sequence of $n$ digits starting from $d_k$, which is $d[k,k+n).$
The expected value of $x$ is equivalent to the expected return time for state $p$. Therefore, the following general fact about Markov chains is relevant:

Fact: If a Markov chain has a unique stationary distribution, where state $s$ has stationary probability $\pi_s$, then the expected return time to state $s$ is $1/\pi_s$.

This Markov chain is an instance of a random walk on a directed graph. Our graph has $L^n$ vertices, one for each sequence of $n$ digits. For each pair of sequences $q_1$ and $q_2$ of $n$ digits, there is a directed edge from $q_1$ to $q_2$ if the last $n-1$ digits of $q_1$
are equal to the first $n-1$ digits of $q_2$, i.e. if $q_1[1,n)=q_2[0,n-1)$.
I claim that this Markov chain has a simple stationary distribution; the distribution where every vertex is equally likely, so vertex $q$ has stationary probability $\pi_q=L^{-n}$. In fact, the same fact is true for a random walk on any directed graph where there is a number $d$ such that every vertex has $d$ incoming edges and $d$ outgoing edges. The current graph has this property; there are $L$ outgoing edges from each $q$, consisting of all ways of a appending a single digit to $q[1,n)$. There are also $L$ incoming edges, one for each way of prepending a digit to $q[0,n-1)$. To prove a distribution is stationary, you just need to show that when the Markov chain has that distribution at a particular step, then one step later, it will still be in that distribution.
I prove this with this calculation. Let $S_k$ denote the $k^\text{th}$ state. Suppose that the $k^\text{th}$ state is uniform over all vertices, so $P(S_k=q)=L^{-n}$ for every vertex $q$. We must now show that the next state is also uniform. For any vertex, $q$, we start by writing
$$
P(S_{k+1}=q)=\sum_{r}P(S_{k+1}=q\mid S_k=r)P(S_k=r)
\\
=\sum_{r}P(S_{k+1}=q\mid S_k=r)L^{-n}
$$
The summation ranges over all vertices $r$. However, $P(S_{k+1}=q\mid S_k=r)$ is only nonzero when there is a directed edge from $r$ to $q$. There are $L$ such vertices $r$, and for each of them, we have $P(S_{k+1}=q\mid S_k=r)$ is equal to $\frac1L$. Therefore,
$$
P(S_{k+1}=q)=L\times \frac1L\times L^{-n}=L^{-n}
$$
This proves $S_{k+1}$ is uniform over all vertices, as claimed.
I have exhibited one stationary distribution. Since the graph is strongly connected, and since there exist closed walks of every possible length, it is a standard result in Markov chain theory that this stationary distribution is unique. Applying the fact, we conclude that expected return time to $p$ is $1/\pi_p=1/(L^{-n})=L^n$, as claimed.

Elegant proof, just amazing. I just want to know if you know a proof using calculations on conditional expectation since I'm not so familiar of proofs involving it.
